# Can there be an icewm tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Its probably one of my favorite window managers.  It would be a shame to never see a tag.  If anyone could add it that would be awesome.  Thanks and regards,
Thomas

Comment: It looks like [you need 300 reputation to do that](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags), but you have to do it using a question. If you have a question you think it applies to, let us know and someone might be able to edit it into the question, creating the tag for everyone's use in the future.

Answer (score 8):

I created a new tag for [icewm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/icewm) and tagged all of the questions about IceWM that needed to be tagged with it.